# Accidentally moved home folder?

Tags: command-line, mv

I'm not quite sure what just happened, all I did was running:

```
~/Desktop$ mv sublime.desktop \~/.local/share/applications/
```

The `\` sign before `~/.local` came up as autocomplete, so I thought it was okay to run it.

But instead of moving the desktop file to `/.local/share/applications/` (which was my intention), the command created new folder on Desktop. (The `~` was folder)

```
Liso@thinkpad:~/Desktop$ ls
~  backup.sql  Apps
```

When I tried to remove `~`:

```
~/Desktop$ rmdir ~
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/home/liso’: Permission denied
```

So what am I missing actually ?

**EDIT**

@Ravexina ask me to ran `test` command to confirm whether it was a directory or a file.

```
Liso@thinkpad:~/Desktop$ test -d \~ && echo "it's a dir"
it's a dir`
```

Comment: just move your file to the correct location with `mv  ~/Desktop/\~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/` and remove the accidently created folders: `rmdir ~/Desktop/\~/.local/share/applications ~/Desktop/\~/.local/share ~/Desktop/\~/.local ~/Desktop/\~`

Comment: Related: [Tilde (~) inside working unix directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139239/117037)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't move your home directory...

- We refer to `~` as tilde expansion, [most of the times](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) it will be  replaced with the value of the `$HOME` shell variable, before the command get executed.
- `\` is the strongest type of [quoting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) in the shell.

So using `\~` you are skipping the tilde expansion by quoting it. Means that you are actually saying: move the "sublime.desktop" to a new file named exactly "~...".

I can't reproduce your command's result, but somehow you ended up with a file/directory exactly named `~`.

Check to see if it's a file or directory and get a list of its contents:

```
test -d ~/Desktop/~ && ls -l ~/Desktop/~ || echo 'it is a file'
```

Then move them to the correct path, if it was a file to move it back you have to escape its name again, otherwise it will be expanded to `/home/liso`:

```
mv \~ new-name
mv "~" new-name # works
mv '~' new-name # also works
mv ~/Desktop/~  new-name # works fine too
```

And remember by `rmdir ~` you are trying to remove the actual home directory: `/home/liso` not the `~`.

Comment: Umm, the `~` wasn't a file like you said. It was actually an folder with `.local/share/application`directory inside.

Comment: Are you sure about the command you ran?

Comment: he's currently on `Destop` so I think the path is `~/Desktop/~/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: @Liso can you give me the output of `ls ~/Desktop~`?

Answer (score 6):

The tilde is expanded by the shell to the $HOME of the user, in your case `/home/liso`. In the first command you escaped the `~` so it was not expanded to the location you wanted, instead it was passed literally to `mv` as the symbol `~`.

I think you wanted to run

```
mv sublime.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

(with an optional trailing `/`)

I would expect the command you say you ran to fail like this

```
mv: cannot move 'sublime.desktop' to '~/.local/share/applications/': No such file or directory
```

because `mv` does not create destination directories like that. If you really did run that command, I think you must have already had a directory actually named `~` in your `Desktop` with that path, ie

```
/home/liso/Desktop/\~/.local/share/applications
```

and if so you will now find a file there:

```
~/Desktop/\~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

And you should run

```
mv ~/Desktop/\~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop ~/.local/share/sublime.desktop
```

But if you ran

```
mv sublime.desktop \~
```

that would create a file `~` because `sublime.desktop` would be renamed `~`. Try reading the file

```
less ~Desktop/\~
```

If it contains the contents of your `sublime.desktop` file, then run

```
mv \~ ~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

Comment: pretty clear to go, assumption, solution and some other ways....

Comment: I don't think you need to escape ~ in the middle of a path

Answer (score 3):

The tilde character is only expanded to your home directory (among other possibilities) when it is not quoted. Putting a `\` character in front of it prevents tilde expansion. When in doubt, use `$HOME` instead, as it is a regular shell variable with a predictable syntax and behavior.

To remove a directory named `~` (make sure there's nothing of importance in it first), you should use the same trick as before: escape the tilde so it's interpreted literally. Oh, and you'll also need to run `rm` recursively to remove a non-empty directory:

```
rm -r "~"
```